# Allauth Override SignupForm & UserProfile Save

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I've been attempting to build my own SignupForm for Allauth and keep running into problems.

When I tried a forms.py like this:

```
class SocialSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ('user',)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.sociallogin = kwargs.pop('sociallogin')
    user = self.sociallogin.user

username = forms.CharField(max_length=25, label="Username", help_text='', required=True)
```

Visually, the form loaded up without any trouble at all. However, when I attempted to submit the form I would get USER_ID is null errors. Presumably, the save method was trying to save the Profile before creating the user. No idea how to change the order of this, and overriding the signup() method as you need to do only runs after the initial save.

I've tried a number of other methods (overriding forms.Form and AllAuth's SocialSignUpForm), without any better luck (although a different set of errors).

Any input/guidance here would be amazing, this has been driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the SocialSignupForm is intended for you to customize the form for the `User` model, so unless `Profile` is your user model (i.e. it derives from `AbstractBaseUser`), you cannot use it here.

If you want to customize the form to add profile information, you should do this in the opposite direction. Define additional fields on the form to use for your Profile, but still keep

```
class Meta:
    model = User   # or whatever your User model is
```

In fact, you should not even define a class Meta and instead derive from the SignupForm:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
class MySignupForm(SignupForm):
    ...
```

You can then overwrite the `custom_signup` or `save` function to try to create the Profile model based on the User model

Or look into doing this using signals.

Comment: Okay, so that totally changed my thinking on it and makes a ton of sense. I refactored the form to inherit from allauth.socialaccount.forms.SignupForm and it seems to generate everything properly. However,  my signup(self, request, user) doesn't seem to do anything. No errors occur but the profile object is never actually saved (heck I can't figure out if signup is even firing)

Comment: Try adding a save and a custom_signup method with just a print statement and see if they get called.

Comment: Save is definitely firing (since the username/email are saved), I tried adding print and messages messages to signup and didn't see anything. I'll try overriding custom_save as well. Where would the print statement appear though?

Comment: Any print command will show on your console ( command shell ) wherever you are running Django from

Comment: When I overloaded custom_save it definitely fired (I added some code to cause it to fail). After that test, I added similar code to signup() and it never went off. For some reason to main form (User) is definitely saving, but it's never getting to the signup function.

Comment: It is possible that signup is only used when doing a regular registration. But maybe you are doing a social login. If all you need is to setup the profile record, you may be able to use signals instead. Let the user signin and login and catch the signal send when logging in. Then check if there is no profile record and if so, redirect user to a regular CreateView

Comment: Odd, I checked the source and the Social Account allauth.socialaccount.forms.SignupForm inherits from allauth.account.forms.BaseSignupForm and the save routine for the social SignupForm includes a call to custom_signup which seems to be what invokes the signup routine.

Comment: If I need to ad a decorator or use signals then I'll juggle things a bit to do that, just seems like a bit of a pain for the user flow wise (initial login -> screen confirming username and possibly e-mail -> profile creation). Now to dig up the correct signal.

Answer (score 1):

For override allauth SignupForm you should follow the steps below:

1. Create the templates directory in your main directory (src directory) and add this dir name to `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py` with this format:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'account')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

2. After that, you should copy and past acount directory (With all the files inside it) from this path(
   `.../your_project_path/your_virtualenv_path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/templates/account`) to new directory with `templates` name.
   My `templates` directory format [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmNhK.png)
3. Be sure to do this:‍

```
ACCOUNTS_FORMS = {
    .
    .
    .
    'signup': 'registerations.form.AllauthSignUpForm', # Notic: You must call your own AllauthSignUpForm
    .
    .
    . 
}
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

‍‍‍‍‍
4. Now you are ready for customization Login, Signup and other allauth templates. so you need create `forms.py` file in your app and override allauth `SignupForm`:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class AllauthSignUpForm(SignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AllauthSignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'] = forms.CharField(
            label='',
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup_name_inp text-right mb-4 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded',
                    'placeholder': 'Username',
                    'dir': 'ltr',
                    'autocomplete': 'off'
                }
            ),
        )
        self.fields['email'] = forms.EmailField(
            label='',
            widget=forms.EmailInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup_mail_inp text-right mb-4 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded',
                    'placeholder': 'email',
                    'dir': 'ltr',
                    'autocomplete':'off',
                    'required': 'True'
                },  
            )
        )
        self.fields['password1'] = forms.CharField(
            label='',
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup_pass_inp1 text-right mb-4 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded',
                    'placeholder': 'password',
                    'dir': 'rtl',
                    'autocomplete': 'off',
                }
            )
        )
        self.fields['password2'] = forms.CharField(
            label='',
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup_pass_inp2 text-right mb-4 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded',
                    'placeholder': 'Repeat password',
                    'dir': 'rtl',
                    'autocomplete': 'off',
                }
            )
        )


    def save(self, request=None):
        # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
        # .save() returns a User object.
        user = super(AllauthSignUpForm, self).save(request)
        # Add your own processing here.
        print(user.username)
        # You must return the original result.
        return user
```

5. And finally you should Implementation your View logic. For example:

```
from .form import AllauthSignUpForm
from allauth.account.views import SignupView

class AllauthSignUpView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'account/signup.html'
    form_class = AllauthSignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('core:home')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AllauthSignUpView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        signUpForm = AllauthSignUpForm(self.request.POST or None)
        context['form'] = signUpForm
        return context
```